# Post Caurosel - Não consigo editar o CSS

Tags: wordpress

Boa tarde pessoal

criei um post caurosel para exibição na página principal de um site que estou desenvolvendo no wordpress

Minha dúvida é a seguinte quando crio o carousel ele gera uma shortcode [post-carousel id="276"] e dessa forma inserimos ele dentro de um página. Eu gostaria de aplicar um efeito em uma imagem deste carousel porém não encontro o css dele. Gostaria de aplicar um efeito ao passar o mouse por cima da imagem ele exibisse uma mensagem

segue o exemplo do código que montei dentro de uma página, dessa forma que eu montei ele aplica o efeito porém  não consigo aplicar somente para a imagem, ele acaba pegando toda a classe.

Se alguém souber como funciona fico muito agradecido.

Obrigado

```css
/*código CSS */
    .descricao {
     background: #493a2ec7;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 356px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 111px;
    display: none;
    padding: 22px 37px;
    width: 355px;
    margin: -64px;
}

.master:hover .descricao {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="recipe"><span>Receitas</span></h2>
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  [post-carousel id="276"] 
 <div class="descricao"><span> APRENDA A FAZER </span> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="mobile-recipe">
  <hr>
 </div>
```

/*código CSS */
    .descricao {
     background: #493a2ec7;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 356px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 111px;
    display: none;
    padding: 22px 37px;
    width: 355px;
    margin: -64px;
}

.master:hover .descricao {
    display: block;
}

Comment: Usa a ferramente de develpor para veres a class da img do carrosel "F12". E depois faz "ctrl+shift+C" e clica na imagem. Depois é só veres as class que usas e editares o CSS, provavelmente pode necessitar de meter como !important os atributos que mudas.

Answer (score 1):

Se for igual ao do demo:http://wordpress.teastudio.pl/category/product/wp-posts-carousel/
A class da img é provavelmente ".wp-posts-carousel-image", logo é só mudar o CSS dessa.

```
.wp-posts-carousel-image:hover{
     //fazer o que tu quiseres quando dá hover
}
```